# jmeter howto conditional result

Tags: jmeter, conditional-statements

I'm using the jmeter GUI to create a load test.  The issue I'm having is trying to figure out how pass or fail an http request, based on both the response code AND a specified string, or strings, in the response body.

Why do I need this?  Two reasons: a response code of 200 doesn't necessarily mean that what was returned, was what I expected. I could receive a response code of 200, but the body of the response is not the response I'm looking for.  In this case, I want to fail the http request.

Also, response code 304 is a successful response, so I want to pass the http request if I get a 304.  Yes, I know you can simply insert a Response Assertion and check for that code, but if I don't get a 304, I want to check the contents of the response body for the expected strings.  If I get the string(s) I'm looking for, I want to pass the http request.  Otherwise, I want to fail the http request.

So here's the pseudo-code for the conditional statement I want to use,....but can't figure out how to do it in the jmeter GUI:

IF responseCode == 304 
    result = pass 
ELSE IF responseText contains "blah"
    result = pass 
ELSE 
    result = fail

Report the http request as a passed or failed response

jmeter won't allow me to have an IF Controller inside an HTTP Request Sampler, nor does it allow you to perform a boolean test within a Response Assertion in order to specify multiple conditions on which to pass or fail a response.

I've tried some other workaround methods, but no luck so far.  Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) provides required flexibility.

Your pseudocode converted to Beanshell should be something like:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("304")) {
    Failure = false;
} 
else if (new String(ResponseData).contains("blah")) {
    Failure = false;
}
else {
    Failure = true;
}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide for comprehensive information on JMeter Assertions including scripting-based ones like Beanshell and JSR223.

Comment: Dmitri, you the man!  That worked.  Using a beanshell script, it allows me to handle the various conditions/states I want to test, as well as output exactly the info I want, on a failure, to the log.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to your test plan. JMeter will automatically mark it as Pass or Fail based on the response it receives.

Comment: Yes, I have Response Assertions already in my test, but you can't setup a Response Assertion to Pass or Fail a response based on more than one condition, and that's my point  (response code AND response body).  I want a 200 response code to only pass if it also has certain strings in the body.  How do you accomplish that?

Comment: You just have to add another assertion under that request and check it there. jMeter set request as failed when at least one of the assertions does not pass. Other thing is that in your pseudo code you suggest usig OR not AND logic.

Comment: No, having two assertions that both need to pass in order for the response pass, won satisfy my pseudo-code example. If both tests need to pass in order for jmeter to pass the response, that doesn't help me. I need the opposite in this case. I need the test to pass if either assertion passes. If neither do, then it should fail.